# Stripe form doesn't show properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, django-templates, stripe-payments

I am building a subscription based website. For the checkout page, the stripe form doesn't show properly.

Here is a screenshot of the problem. 
[image: screenshot image]
I looked to make sure that my scripts aren't overriding any element from stripe but i still have this problem. You can see below the `checkout.html`, `checkout.css` and `checkout.js`.

checkout.html

```html
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block head%}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Checkout</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/checkout.css' %}">
    <style>
      #checkoutMethods {
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        display: inline-block;
        max-height: 700px;
        margin: 1rem;
        position: relative;
        width: 700px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);

      }
    </style>
</head>
{% endblock head%}
{% block content %}
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <section>
      <div class="row" id="tablerow">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">

          <div class="panel-body">
            <h5>Enter Voucher Code Below<br><small>If multiple, separate each with comma</small></h5>

            <div>
              <form action="." method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text"  name="voucher_codes" class="form-control" id="voucher_code" required>
                <input type="hidden"  name="order_id" value="{{ order.id }}">
                <br>
                <span>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" value="Apply Voucher"> 
                </span>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td><h4>Order Summary</h4></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {% for item in order.get_cart_items %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ item }}</td>
                  <td>${{ item.product.price }}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Order Total</strong> </td>
            <td> <strong>${{ order.get_cart_total }}</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button onclick="toggleDisplay();" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 100%;">Checkout with a credit card</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>


<div id="collapseStripe" class="wrapper">
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  <!-- can't do this -->
  <!-- <script src="{% static 'js/stripeV3.js' %}"></script> -->

  <form action="." method="post" id="payment-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="checkoutMethods">
      <div style="margin: 10px;">
        <h2>Checkout with Braintree</h2>
        <div id="bt-dropin"></div>
        <h2>Checkout with Stripe</h2>
        <div class="form-row">
          <label for="card-element">
            Credit or debit card
          </label>
          <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty"><div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame3" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-8a434729e4eb82355db4882974049278.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][lineHeight]=18px&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;features[noop]=false&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js%2Felements%2Fquickstart&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController0" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; height: 18px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-safariInput" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div></div>

          <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
          <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="nonce" name="payment_method_nonce" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button>Submit Payment</button>
  </form>

  </div>

  <div id="stripe-token-handler" class="is-hidden">Success! Got token: <span class="token"></span></div>

</div>

<!-- script for the stripe form -->
<script src="{% static 'js/checkout.js' %}"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.13.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');
  var client_token = '{{ client_token }}';

  braintree.dropin.create({
    authorization: client_token,
    container: '#bt-dropin',
    paypal: {
      flow: 'vault'
    }
  }, function (createErr, instance) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error', err);
          return;
        }

        // Add the nonce to the form and submit
        document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
        form.submit();
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- script for toggling display of the form -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDisplay() {
      var x = document.getElementById("collapseStripe");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
    };
</script>

</body>
{% endblock content %}
```

checkout.css

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f8f9;
  color: #6b7c93;
}

*, label {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #32325d;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 28px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  background-color: #43458b;
}

form {
  padding: 300px;
  height: 1200px;
}

label {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#card-errors {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  color: #fa755a;
}

.form-row {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.token {
  color: #32325d;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 670px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#stripe-token-handler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 100px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1),
    0 15px 35px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.15),
    0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

#stripe-token-handler.is-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}

/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
.StripeElement {
  background-color: white;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
```

checkout.js

```js
// Create a Stripe client.

var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_1gVJE1B3TYjY3ykiEhZgWeGe00mRO0lVwa');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      lineHeight: '18px',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });

  });

  var successElement = document.getElementById('stripe-token-handler');
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
    successElement.className = 'is-hidden';
  });

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    successElement.className = '';
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = token.id;
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you put the HTML/CSS/JS into a jsfiddle.net recreating the problem? Likely you have some inherited CSS somewhere which is messing with the element's width.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure your `clientSecrect` key, that you are getting from your backend, is being received properly. Otherwise the stripe Elements do not render, it only renders when you provide the stripe Elements with your `clientSecret` as a prop.

You can refer to their documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create